# How can I log my errors into a txt file AND the console in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

How can I log my errors into a txt file AND the console in nodejs?

I want to be able to keep all my errors in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what framework you want to use.

You can use [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston), which has the support for [Transports](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#transports) - enabling you to create different outputs (file, tcp, stdout etc.) for your logs (based on level and other rules)

Answer (score 0):

Use morgan

```
const fs = require('fs');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const logs = fs.createWriteStream(
  path.join(__dirname, 'logs.log'),
  { flags: 'a' }
);

app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: logs }));
```

Answer (score -1):

In terms of pure Node.js functionality that works irrespective of frameworks or libraries, `console.log()` writes data to [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout), which is a stream that you can listen to. You can attach a listener function for [the `data` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data), and write console.log both to "the console" as well as to file that way.

Alternatively, you can pipe `process.stdout` into a file, but that's far more tricky to get right.

Also note that if you also yo log error output as well, you'll need to listen for data on `process.stderr` in addition to `process.stdout`.